# Save items of a list of objects

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have the following Class:

```
public class Student : ModelObject
{
    private string name;
    private string id;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
```

And I have the following list

```
protected List<Student> studentlist = new List<Student>();
```

This list is already full with Student Objects and what I want to achieve is to make a list of string for example:

```
List<string> ownlist = new List<string>();
```

That saves the id of each Object.

The idea is to grab the content of the list studentlist that it is already full and for each element of that list (that is, objects) save the value of id as an element of ownlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. First - simple iterative:

```
foreach(var item in studentlist)
{
   ownList.Add(item.Id);
}
```

Second - by Linq:

```
List<string> ownlist = studentlist.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

And many others.

Comment: I was thinking about LINQ but as I'm still a rookie and Delegate nomenclature still eludes me I wasn't sure how to do it.
Apreciate the Answer

Comment: Use a `Dictionary` where the `key` is the `id` and the `value` is the `Student`

Comment: Your second option will throw invalid cast exception

Comment: @Fabio, why should it throw an exception? Id has a type of string

Comment: Just run it. `List.Select(...)` will return IEnumerable while expecting type is `List`. use `.ToList()` `studentlist.Select(x => x.id).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use C# Dictionary :

```
Dictionary<int, Student> record = new Dictionary<int, Student>
foreach(Student std in studentlist)
{
  records.Add(std.Id, std);
}
```